# Subdividing chapters into A, B, ... without using sections

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

For my class (teaching at university) I use a TeX document to provide the assignments and excercises for every week as shown below.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle~}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\color{blue}\Large\bfseries}{Exercise \thechapter\,--\,}{0sp}{\color{blue}}[]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Topic of Week 1}
\section{Task 1}
\section{Task 2}
\chapter{Topic of Week 2}
\section{Task 1}
\section{Task 2}
\end{document}
```

This generates chapter headings such as *Excercise 1 - Topic of Week 1*. Now I need a solution to split a chapter across two weeks, i.e. it should result in

- Excercise 1A - Topic of Week 1
- Excercise 1B - Remainder of Week 1

Since thas `\sections` are the tasks I switch to `\section` and `\subsection` as the overall structure should remain the same. Actually I'd like to add a new `\chapter{Remainder of Week 1}` but do not (visibly) increase the chapter counter.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure, that I understand, what you expect, but maybe `\chapter*{Remainder of Week 1}`? BTW: Your example does not compile. At least package `color` or `xcolor` is missing.

Comment: Do you mean that every chapter the sections should start counting at 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option just using `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec,xcolor}

\titlelabel{\thetitle~}
\titleformat{\chapter}
    [hang]
    {\color{blue}\Large\bfseries}
    {Exercise \thechapter\,--\,}
    {0sp}
    {\color{blue}}
    []

\titleclass{\splitchapter}{top}[\part]

\newcounter{splitchapter}

\renewcommand{\thesplitchapter}{\thechapter\Alph{splitchapter}}

\titleformat{\splitchapter}
    [hang]
    {\ifnum\value{splitchapter}=1\refstepcounter{chapter}\else\fi
        \color{blue}\Large\bfseries}
    {Exercise \thesplitchapter\,--\,}
    {0sp}
    {\color{blue}}
    []
    
% copied from titlesec doc
\titlespacing*{\splitchapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}

% reset splitchapter counter at each chapter
\AddToHook{cmd/chapter/before}{\setcounter{splitchapter}{0}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{a chapter}
\section{abc}
\section{abc}
\splitchapter{a split chapter}
\section{abc}
\section{abc}
\splitchapter{another split chapter}
\section{abc}
\section{abc}
\chapter{another  chapter}
\section{abc}
\section{abc}
\splitchapter{split}
\section{abc}
\end{document}
```

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, that I understand, what you expect. Maybe you just search for `\chapter*`. But maybe you want something like the following, which would need to change the class:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{color}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{Exercise \thechapter\,--\,}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{blue}}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[% see the KOMA-Script manual for more information
  style=chapter,
  level=\chapternumdepth,% same level as chapter
  beforeskip:=chapter,% same value as of chapter
  afterskip:=chapter,% same value as of chapter
  font:=chapter,% same value as of chapter
  counterwithin=chapter,% same value as of chapter
]{subchapter}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entryformat:=chapter,indent:=chapter,numwidth:=chapter,numwidth+=.5em,pagenumberformat:=chapter,beforeskip:=chapter]{chapter}{subchapter}% may be useful for the ToC; see the KOMA-Script manual for more information
\renewcommand*{\thesubchapter}{\thechapter\Alph{subchapter}}
\renewcommand*{\subchapterformat}{Exercise \thesubchapter\,--\,}

\begin{document}
\refstepcounter{chapter}% unfortunately needed, if the numbering should not be 1, 1A, 1B but 1A, 1B without a 1 before
\subchapter{Topic of Week 1}
\section{Task 1}
\section{Task 2}
\subchapter{Remainder of Week 1}
\section{Task 3}
\section{Task 4}
\chapter{Topic of Week 2}
\section{Task 1}
\section{Task 2}
\end{document}
```

[image: three pages with Exercise 1A, 1B and 2]

But maybe you want also 1A.1, 1A.2, 1B.1, 1B.2 for the section numbering? In this case, you could use something like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle~}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\color{blue}\Large\bfseries}{Exercise \thechapter\,--\,}{0sp}{\color{blue}}[]

\newcounter{realchapter}
\newenvironment{subtopic}{%
  \clearpage
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%
  \setcounter{realchapter}{\value{chapter}}%
  \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\therealchapter\Alph{chapter}}%
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
}{%
  \clearpage
}

\begin{document}
\begin{subtopic}
\chapter{Topic of Week 1}
\section{Task 1}
\section{Task 2}
\chapter{Remainder of Week 1}
\section{Task 1}
\section{Task 2}
\end{subtopic}
\chapter{Topic of Week 2}
\section{Task 1}
\section{Task 2}
\end{document}
```

[image: here the sections are numbered 1A.1, 1A.2, 1B.1, 1B.2]